# Trying to get a value from a JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to access a value in a json file using python. In the imgur link, the value I am trying to access is the "NUM" nested in "args". My main logic is reading in the JSON file, then using pandas to normalize the json.I have tried using .loc to try and find 'args' but I need help with another way or option.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6hOg.png

Here is my code snippet along with the terminal error I am getting

```
def readInJSON(json):
    df = pandas.json_normalize(json)
    goto_rows = [i for i in df.loc[df['mnemonic'] == 'PLD_CCD_EXPOSE_CLOSED'].index]
    commandDates = list(df['utc_time'])
    numIDs =  list(df['args'])  #tried using list typing 
    print(type(df['args']))  #couldnt get a typing from it either 
    args = df['args']        #tried just using it like a regular list 
    args = [i for i in df.loc[df['args']]]  #tried using .loc from pandas as well
```

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3505, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: 'args'

Comment: Is it possible that you provide an example of input JSON here?

Comment: Do you have "args" present as a column in the input "JSON -> DataFrame"?

Comment: What, exactly, is the *json* object being passed to this function? What should this function return (currently doesn't return anything). What if there are multiple occurrences of NUM in the sub-dictionaries? Why are you using *pandas* for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access value of `NUM`:

```
import json

file = open('data.json')

data = json.load(file)

NUM = data[1]["args"]["NUM"]

# NUM = 20.0

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure appears to be a list of dictionaries. Those dictionaries may or may not have a 'args' key. The value associated with 'args' is expected to be a dictionary. That dictionary may contains a 'NUM' key. If 'NUM' exists, append its value to a list. Return the list.

```
def readInJSON(json):
    numvals = []
    for d in json:
        if (args := d.get('args')):
            if isinstance(args, dict) and (num := args.get('NUM')):
                numvals.append(num)
    return numvals
```

A better approach might be to write the function so that it handles the input JSON file like this:

```
import json

def readInJSON(filename):
    with open(filename) as jdata:
        numvals = []
        for d in json.load(jdata):
            if (args := d.get('args')):
                if isinstance(args, dict) and (num := args.get('NUM')):
                    numvals.append(num)
        return numvals
```